# Finder: why is a *.wmv movie a "document" and not a movie? Howto correct?

Tags: finder, macos, video, file-extensions, document-management

See screen shot of my Finder settings

[image]

all folders and movies (flv, divx, mkv and mov) are correct categorized, only *.wmv file is a document. Should be movie.

[image]

Howto correct that?

```
> ls -l@ *.wmv                                                                                                      
-rw-r--r--@ 1 john  staff  224665155 Jun 12 17:35 sweet-cat-imgur.wmv
        com.apple.quarantine           26
```

Comment: From Terminal, what's the output of `ls -l@ filename.wmv` where "filename" is the name of the file you have blacked out in the image you posted.

Comment: @user3439894 made an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to do this answer myself to make it easier to explain to you but that answer is over complex, I bet it is something really small.. But here it is:

https://superuser.com/a/371939

If this worked for you, let us know what you did, in a better way please! :)